# Python, Spyder IDE - matplotlib does not plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I'm using:
Python 2.7.3
matplotlib 1.4.1
Spyder IDE 2.3.8

My code has to produce a chart (combination of bar and scatter) . First run on the code succeeds in that, however all following executions (both run or debug) produce just an empty chart with correct grid, label, and legend, but no bars not scatter plot. I have to close Python console and open a new one to get the correct plot, and then the story repeats. In debugger I can see that all the data for the chart is fine.

I also tried Wing IDE (ver 5.1.10-1), and the very same code works fine all the time.

I found some suggestions about setting console preferences in Spyder (ie set GUI backend to Qt4Agg, agg, TkAgg, MAcOSX, Inline and such - none of those had any effect)

I would appreciate any help with this, as I'd prefer to use Spyder.
Many thanks

P.S. I used an earlier version of matplotlib without any issues, but recently I had to update it to ver 1.4.1 to use some libraries in an unrelated software project.

Comment: Share your code and a [mcve] or there's not much we can do to help.

Comment: Try using the mouse to resize the output window.  Sometimes it does not refresh properly when loading a new image.